# Maximum number of Event Action created in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have a question related with google analytics. First I am using free account of google analytics and using Measurement protocal. I am using this because I want to track desktop applications.

I want to know how many Event Action we can create which is shown under Behavior / Events / Top Events and Then Event Action. For more specific information please see in below image.

[image]

I am asking this question because I have to deploy this solution on 12000 customers and so it will create atleast 12000 event action and each have seperate list of events. I am specifically interested to know that is there are any limit for Event Action.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the limits Ethaan mentioned, but these are related to how you track them. If you change the cid, so it looks like it comes from a different user every hit you send this should not be a problem.

Once you are past that issue what you have here is a problem of cardinality. Google Analytics allows you to send as many events as you want, but when you do a report it might show you only a subset of these events.

It's currently limited to 50,000 different combinations of category + action + label for events. If you have more than that in any given report Google Analytics might group some inside a row called (other)

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671?hl=en