# Is there any limit on number of Event Category, Action, Label & Values?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am working on google analytics for tracking user behavior on my website. I want to know if there is any limit on number of Event Categories, Action, Label & Values? I want to know limit for each individual action metric.

I have seen an answer which say I can use 50,000 combinations of event categories, action & label. 
[Maximum number of Event Action created in Google analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212217/maximum-number-of-event-action-created-in-google-analytics)

I want to know limit for each individual action metric. i.e. Event Category, Event Action, Event Label & Event Value. Because I have to track a lot of user interaction with website.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are linking is over four years old and the system has changed since then.  The page it links no longer contains any information about a limit.  Nor i there any limit in the actual documentation page for [Events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) my guess is that this is there may be a limit but its undocumented because they want to be free to change it.

If you want to find the current limit i think your going to have to submit stuff until it stops accepting it.

However if it helps I will ping the team for you one of them may or may not respond to your question and give you a more concrete answer.

## response from the team

> I would just point to what is documented.
>
> The one thing to consider is high-cardinality dimensions which can affect number of rows returned. see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671

Comment: Thankyou DalmTo for the response. Can you please ask for concrete answer from team?